# FileReader.onload never fired in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, filereader

I've got the following lines of code. I had it working yesterday but today the reader.onload event is never called which results in not getting in that function. Any idea how this could come or why it's not firing?

```
fileChange(event) {
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    var file = fileList[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
    }

    _handleReaderLoaded(readerEvt) {
      var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
      this.base64textString= btoa(binaryString);
      console.log(btoa(binaryString));
      this.photo.image = this.image;
      this.photo.title = 'test';
      this.photo.image.data = btoa(binaryString);
      this.formData.sessionPhoto = this.photo;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to read file: [`reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer)

```
fileChange(event) {
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    var file = fileList[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```